# Java program printing unicode values instead of string

Tags: java, string, unicode, output

I am trying to add 2 binary string but getting result in Unicode

**Input:** `"11""1"`

**Output:** `"\u0001\u0000\u0000"`

I want my answer as `100`

```
class Solution {
    public String addBinary(String a, String b) {
        String ans=new String();
        int i=a.length()-1;
        int j=b.length()-1;
        int carry=0;
        while(i>=0 || j>=0 || carry==1){
            int add=carry;
            if(i>=0) add+=a.charAt(i)-'0';
            if(j>=0) add+=b.charAt(j)-'0';
            ans=(char)(add%2)+ans;
            carry=add/2;
            i--;
            j--;
        }
        return ans;    
    }
}
```

Comment: first never do this `String ans=new String();` always use `String ans=""`

Comment: How does that help?

Comment: @user13784117 this is just a FYI.

Comment: Just remove `(char)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding at the beginning of another string part is not correct. you need to use `ans="" + (add%2) + ans;`

```
public String addBinary(String a, String b) {
    String ans="";
    int i=a.length()-1;
    int j=b.length()-1;
    int carry=0;
    
    while(i>=0 || j>=0 || carry==1){
        int add=carry;
        if(i>=0) add+=a.charAt(i)-'0';
        if(j>=0) add+=b.charAt(j)-'0';
        ans="" + (add%2) + ans;
        carry=add/2; 
        i--;
        j--;
    }
    
    System.out.print("ans=" +  ans);
    return ans;    
}
```

https://ideone.com/sn709k

Comment: I suspect your answer works not because of the addition of the `""` term but because you dropped the cast to char.  The `+` operator is string concatenation if either operand is a string.  With the cast, the char with value 0,1,... is simply prefixed to the string (i.e. no conversion needed). Without the cast, the int value is converted to a string (so 0 => '0',  etc) before being prefixed.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've figured out the value to be appended to your result string, you need to convert the binary value (0, 1, …) back to a character ('0', '1', …).

This:

```
ans=(char)(add%2)+ans;
```

should be this:

```
ans = (char)((add%2) + '0') + ans;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Parse the two `String`(s) and add the values. Return the result as a `String` of binary digits. And I'd make it a `static` method. Like,

```
public static String addBinary(String a, String b) {
    return Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(a, 2)
            + Integer.parseInt(b, 2));
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(addBinary("1", "11"));
}
```

Outputs (as requested)

```
100
```

Comment: I assume (thought it was not stated) that the point of the exercise is not to use the built-in classes but to figure out the algorithms.  I could be wrong, though.

Comment: the approach is right, but at some point(when the string is large) it will through a NumberFormatException @user13784117